# How can I return a series of cells that match any of a series of headers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an array that I want to pull all values under each header that matches a list from another sheet. Example:

sheet 1:

| Alan | Cindy | Joe | Brad | Jenny |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| a | b | c | d | e |

sheet 2:

| List |
| --- |
| Alan |
| Joe |
| Brad |

I want this to return the values under the names that match the list. So in this situation it would return:

| output |
| --- |
| 1 |
| a |
| 3 |
| c |
| 4 |
| d |

Comment: What version do you have?  Also, please show what you have tried to accomplish this, otherwise it will seem that you are asking us to do this for you.  And that is not what this site is about.

Comment: This might help you map the data between sheets: https://www.exceldemy.com/link-data-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find out all data that match the headers.

The formula could be `=INDEX($A$1:$E$3,COLUMN(B1),MATCH($H2,$A$1:$E$1,0))` based on my simple sample.

[image]

Then we can merge 2 columns into one.

The formula could be `=INDEX($I$2:$J$4,ROUNDUP(ROW(I1)/2,),MOD(ROW(I1)-1,2)+1)`.

[image]

Please note, to get the the row number, the formula **ROUNDUP(ROW(I1)/2,)** is fixed, and it is not changed with your data range.

The same goes for column number formula **MOD(ROW(I1)-1,2)+1**.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `FILTER` for this kind of thing, but it won't directly work across columns. Using `TRANSPOSE` though, solves that:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(A2:E3),TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FIND(A1:E1,ARRAYTOTEXT(H1:H3)),0))))
```

This makes an array of the elements that one is looking for in the data set (I have them in H1:H3 of my working model) using `ARRAYTOTEXT` as the examples are not complex. If they were, a `TEXTJOIN` using something like `|` for its delimiter would be an idea. Then `FIND` is applied using the column headers as values to find in the array. That produces number values and errors, the latter becoming 0's via `IFERROR`. That is done to produce a TRUE/FALSE array for `FILTER` to use in choosing which columns' data to output. It will be in the form of `{0,0,4,0,0,0,28,0,0,83}`, i.e:  zeros and non-zeros, but ALL numbers. That works because when Excel looks at it as a Boolean array, it sees any non-zero NUMBER value as TRUE. Anything non-numerical becomes problematic hence the efforts to get here where all the values are numbers of some kind.

One must `TRANPOSE` the rows desired as output (do not include the header row since you do not desire it in the output) so that `FILTER` thinks it is working on rows since it refuses to work directly on a columnar basis.

In any case, one now has a "3 columns by 2 rows" 2-D array as output using the example data. Since a single column is desired, use `TOCOL` choosing a columnar output to achieve the desired output:

```
=TOCOL(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(A2:E3),TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FIND(A1:E1,ARRAYTOTEXT(H1:H3)),0)))),,TRUE)
```

and that's all that is needed.

If one prefers, one can always use `INDEX` to achieve the transpositioning. I did not experiment it, but it can transpose all four ways, not just the two `TRANSPOSE` can achieve, and it's possible, it would have needed done just once. Also,if one wanted a "1,3,4,a,c,d" output rather than the "1,a,3,c,4,d" output, it's a minor tweak.

The real key here is using `TOCOL` to produce the single column output.